# running knitr and pandoc for HTML5 slides

Tags: r, knitr, pandoc, shiny

I have a .Rmd file and hope to get the slides using `knitr` and `pandoc`. After running:

```
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(message = FALSE)
knit("my_file.Rmd")
pandoc("my_file.md", format="dzslides")
```

I got the following error message:

```
Error in system(paste(which, shQuote(names[i])), intern = TRUE, ignore.stderr = TRUE) : 
  cannot popen '/usr/bin/which 'pandoc' 2>/dev/null', probable reason 'Cannot allocate memory'
```

What is the problem? Thanks!

Comment: I have been using the slidify package to do this. Slidify rocks. It means you don't need the pandoc step.

Comment: did you install pandoc?